# Wrapper hierarchies with Java generics

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

Is there any way using Java generics to express a type hierarchy like the following?

```
class A { ... }

class B extends A { ... }

interface Wraps<T> {
  T getWrapped();
}

class WrapsA implements Wraps<A> {
  A getWrapped();
}

class WrapsB extends WrapsA /* implements Wraps<B> */ {
  B getWrapped();
}
```

I understand that as written Java's type system will reject this code, but is there any way I can specify the type parameters or inheritance hierarchy that will get this working?

EDIT: I realized that the real issue I'm having is I'm trying to enforce type safety in my API for a method like

```
<T extends A> T unwrap(Wraps<T> wrapper, Class<T> wrappedClass);
```

I'm not able to call it with `unwrap(wrapsB, B.class)`. Is this something that Java will handle?

Answer (score 2):

You can just use

```
class WrapsB extends WrapsA {
    B getWrapped();
}
```

Since you're allowed to return subclasses in overriden methods (it's possible from Java SE6, as far as I remember)

Comment: Right, but clients expecting a Wraps<B> won't accept an instance of WrapsB

Comment: Ah, and I'm realizing now that my real issue is I want to be able to handle the situation Judge Mental mentions.

Comment: @Greg ah, I see. Before I can propose another solution, could you please answer the question - do you really need `WrapsB` to extend `WrapsA`? Is `WrapsA` performs some logic (except of providing `A`, of course)?

Comment: Ideally WrapsB should be usable anywhere that WrapsA is, and inheritance seems to be the simplest way to provide that. There will be shared code, but that can probably be handled by a helper class. What are the different options if `WrapsB` extends `WrapsA` or not? I apologize if my answers are somewhat disjointed. Thinking about this has been giving me a headache.

Answer (score 0):

Check out self-bounded types.

```
interface Wraps<T, W extends Wraps<T, W>> { ... }

abstract class AbstractWrapsA< T extends A, W extends AbstractWrapsA< T, W > implements Wraps< T, W > { ... }
class WrapsA extends AbstractWrapsA< A, WrapsA > {}
class WrapsB extends AbstractWrapsA< B, WrapsB > { ... }
```

**EDIT**:  Actually to satisfy the OP's need we can dispense with self-bounded types and just migrate the guts of `WrapsA` to an abstract class.  We still do not have that `WrapsB` both is-a `WrapsA` and is-a `Wraps<B>`.